# Customizing ReceiptCard for Microsoft Bot-Builder

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm currently trying to create a ReceiptCard that shows outstanding balance for a target account. Is there any way to remove the Tax and Total fields from the generated card when it is displayed in the Bot Framework Emulator?

Method for generating ReceiptCards

```
private ReceiptCard GenerateNewReceiptCardAccount(Account account)
{
    return new ReceiptCard()
    {
        Title = "Account Number: " + account.AccountNumber.ToUpperInvariant(),

        Facts = new List<Fact>
        {
            new Fact("Reference Month:", account.MonthRef),
        },

        Items = GetReceiptItemListAccount(account),

        Buttons = new List<CardAction>
        {
            new CardAction(
                ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                "More Details",
                "https://github.com/amido/azure-vector-icons/blob/master/renders/file.png",
                "https://gmail.com")
        }
    };
}
```

Method for generating ReceiptItems

```
private List<ReceiptItem> GetReceiptItemListAccount(Account account)
{
    List<ReceiptItem> ri = new List<ReceiptItem>();

    ri.Add(new ReceiptItem("30-Days Outstanding Balance", price: "$ " + account.Outstanding30Days.ToString("F")));
    ri.Add(new ReceiptItem("Current Outstanding Balance", price: "$ " + account.OutstandingCurrent.ToString("F")));
    ri.Add(new ReceiptItem("Total Outstanding Balance", price: "$ " + account.OutstandingTotal.ToString("F")));

    return ri;
}
```

The result I'm getting right now in the Emulator window:
[image: ReceiptCardEmulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PR fixes the issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/603 by ensuring tax and total have a value before showing.

It just isn't in the latest emulator yet.  It is in the WebChat control, available here: https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js & https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css

Pro Tip:
You can also these files and replace the ones under C:\Users[YourUserName]\AppData\Local\botframework\ on windows - updating your local emulator.